# WordPress not disabling the auto hyphenation

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress page I wanted to disable the auto hyphenation. So I went to the source css and changed the all the `-moz-hyphens: auto` and `hyphen: auto` to `none`. I even added `!important` so it would read them.

I made the changes on both the child and parent stylesheets, but the hyphens were still there, and when I inspected the elements in the google dev tool all the hyphens were still set to auto. I deleted the cache and nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: why you want to remove hyphen?

Comment: cuz thats what my boses told me to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, all I had to do was change all the -moz-hyphens: none to manual.